# Can't upload image to Cloudinary from Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra, carrierwave, ruby-datamapper, cloudinary

I'm trying to upload an image to Cloudinary from within my Sinatra web app. I
got it saving the image locally by using CarrierWave and I know Cloudinary and
CarrierWave play nicely with each other but I've tried everything and no dice.

I've followed the docs but they are very Rails-centric. Damn you Rails!

```
# Model - User.rb
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include Cloudinary::CarrierWave

  process convert: 'png'
  version :face do
    cloudinary_transformation gravity: :face
  end
end

class User
  include DataMapper::Resource

  attr_accessor :image
  property.............
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end

# Config - app.rb

require 'carrierwave/datamapper'
require 'cloudinary'

# DataMapper code ...
# Some routes ...

post '/add' do
  user = user.create(name: params[:name])
  Cloudinary::Uploader.upload(params[:image], api_key: 'API_KEY', api_secret: 'API_SECRET', cloud_name: 'CLOUD_NAME')

# View (haml)
%head
  %script{src: "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"}
  %script{src: "js/cloudinary_js/jquery.ui.widget.js"}               
  %script{src: "js/cloudinary_js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"}        
  %script{src: "js/cloudinary_js/jquery.fileupload.js"}              
  %script{src: "js/cloudinary_js/jquery.cloudinary.js"}
  # snip snip ...
%form{action: "/add", method: "POST", enctype: "multipart/form-data"}
  %input{type: "file", name: "image"}
  %button Submit
```

The error I'm getting when trying to submit the form is:

```
TypeError at /add
no implicit conversion of Hash into String
```

The line it gives me that is causing the error is the Cloudinary uploader line in the post method.

Here's my params[:image] hash

```
{:filename=>"batman_robin.jpg", :type=>"image/jpeg", :name=>"image", :tempfile=>#<Tempfile:/var/folders/rv/2w8gpstn4hb2lb__27n27ksh0000gn/T/RackMultipart20131223-36484-tgmaba>, :head=>"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"batman_robin.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n"}
```

In the docs it mentions a file signature then states that CarrierWave handles this. I think my problem lies with the upload form.

Where am I going wrong with this? Anyone know what 'cl_image_upload_tag' generates and what are Cloudinary's "special attributes" that I need to add to my file upload tag?

**UPDATE**: So I figured that and I can actually just pass the image directly like so:

```
Cloudinary::Uploader.upload(params[:image][:filename] ...
```

However it now says

```
No such file or directory - batman_robin.jpg
```

which is strange. I've hardcoded a URL in there and it gets uploaded to Cloudinary. Any ideas? Also, any idea about the Cloudinary jQuery upload?

Answer (score 1):

`params[:image]` is a hash but `Cloudinary::Uploader.upload` expects a string as the first argument. All the [examples](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/rails_image_upload) [in the docs](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/rails_integration#upload_images) give a name or a URL, so pass the `:filename` from the params, e.g.

```
post '/add' do
  user = user.create name: params[:name]
  image_meta = params[:image]
  filename = image_meta.delete :filename
  Cloudinary::Uploader.upload filename, {api_key: 'API_KEY', api_secret: 'API_SECRET', cloud_name: 'CLOUD_NAME'}.merge(image_meta)
```

I'd also put all those default settings into a `settings` hash (and have them read in from the environment if they're secret), e.g.

```
config do
  set :cloudinary_api, {api_key: ENV['API_KEY'],
                        api_secret: ENV['API_SECRET'],
                        cloud_name: ENV['CLOUD_NAME']}
end
```

then the call becomes…

```
Cloudinary::Uploader.upload filename, settings.cloudinary_api.merge(image_meta)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the filename you need to pass the actual content which is hold in `Tempfile` So passing `Cloudinary::Uploader.upload(params[:image][:tempfile])` should work.